# Solr 8.1.0 - Get terms frequency for partials words

Tags: search, solr, wildcard

I have the following documents :

```
doc1
    description: "A doggo is a small dog."
doc2
    description: "My dog is small.
doc3
    description: "My cat is lazy."
```

I search through my documents with the following query :

```
description:*dog* OR small
```

which returns the documents : `doc1` and `doc2`

Now I want get the total of terms frequency of each words in the query. For that I'm trying to use the `termfreq()` function.

```
termfreq(description, *dog*)
termfreq(description, small)
```

The result will look like that :

```
doc1
    description: "A doggo is a small dog."
    termfreq(description,*dog*): 0
    termfreq(description, small): 1
doc2
    description: "My dog is small.
    termfreq(description, *dog*): 0
    termfreq(description, small): 1
```

Or the result should look like that :

```
doc1
    description: "A doggo is a small dog."
    termfreq(description, *dog*): 2
    termfreq(description, small): 1
doc2
    description: "My dog is small.
    termfreq(description, *dog*): 1
    termfreq(description, small): 1
```

My question : Is it possible to use wildcard character in the termfreq function ?

- If `yes` : How ?
- If `no` : Is there a way to get the terms frequency of a query with partial words ?

EDIT :

managed-schema

```xml
<fieldType name="descriptionNGram" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

<field name="description" stored="true" type="descriptionNGram" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without having a prefix wildcard, you can [use the TermsComponent](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-terms-component.html) with `terms.lower` set to the token to start iterating from.

If you need the prefix wildcard, you'll have to index NGrams instead, so that you get [one token per combination of letters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html) in your words. So for doggo, you'll get tokens with `do`, `og`, `gg`, `go`, etc.

Comment: I need the prefix wildcard so I can't use terms.lower. For the Ngrams can you provide an example for how to use it ? I've configured my field with the filter `NGramFilterFactory` but the results are still the same with the termfreq function.

Comment: If you've already configured the ngramfilter, add the configuration to your question - and make sure that you're only asking for the termfreq of `dog` in that case - not `*dog*`.

Comment: According to your update you've used an EdgeNGramTokenizer - it'll only generate ngrams from the _start of the string_. You've also used the type for the `description` field and not for the `text` field which you're retrieving termfreqs for.

Comment: The EdgeNGramTokenizer will not tokenize on whitespace, etc. It'll only generate tokens of varying length from your input. Use a regular tokenizer (Standard or Whitespace) with an NGramFilterFactory to get the behavior you're asking for.

Comment: I've updated the fields and filter but I still don't get the good results. Did I'm still missing something ?

Comment: You still have to ask for the termfreq for `dog` without wildcards, and you have to reindex your content first.